# СИ. Сравнение в условии. Функции языка. Сравнение char и массива char

Tags: c++, c

Столкнулся с необходимостью в такой конструкции

```
char name[] = "неважно";
if ((name[i] == 'У') || (name[i] == 'Е' )|| (name[i] == 'Ё') /*|| ...*/)
{
    //...
}
```

**Есть ли более лаконичные способы реализации подобного условия?**
*По идее в стандартной библиотеке вероятно должна быть функция возвращающая `true`/`false` после поиска символа в массиве символов, но я чет не нашел; а самому раздувать код такой функцией чет не айс. Help*

Comment: регулярку использовать надо

Comment: регулярку??? перефразируйте пожалуйста

Comment: Нет там такой функции, реализуйте ее самостоятельно. Стоит отметить, что представленный вариант делает совершенно не то, что нужно. Кроме того, если не использовать однобайтовую кодировку, `char` не может содержать кириллический символ целиком.

Comment: У меня проблем с 1 байтовым char не было написал setlocale(0,"RU"); и всё. Я б взял массив на 256 символов и заполнил единицами где нужно.

Comment: Конструкция то есть std::regex_search но это 100% оверкилл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже сказали, подобное условие априори не работоспособно. Корректный вариант выглядел бы как:

```
if ((name[i] == 'У') || (name[i] == 'Е' )|| (name[i] == 'Ё') /*|| ...*/)
```

Во-вторых, использование кириллицы в исходниках сопрежено с определёнными сложностями, но т.к. вопрос не об этом, то предполагаю, что используется какая-то однобайтовая 8-битная локаль. Для переносимости в данном случае нужно будет испоьзовать широкие символы (`wchar_t`).

> Есть ли более лаконичные способы реализации подобного условия?

Да, в стандартной библиотеке есть `strchr`:

```
if (strchr("УЕЁЫАОЭЯИЮЬЪуеёыаоэяиюьъ", name[i])) // ...
```

Если символ найден, то она возвращает указатель на первое вхождение символа в строку, что является не нулевым значением, а следовательно означает истинность. В противным случае она возвращает `NULL`, что равносильно ложности условия.

Аналогичная многобайтовая функция зовётся `wcschr()`.

Comment: можно пользоваться и стандартным альгоритмом  find_first_of